# CListCtrl: Get DblClick on HeaderControl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

Okay, it's been I while I wrote something in MFC, so please be patient with me. I have a class "CMyListCtrl" derived from CListCtrl and just want to know if a column-header has been double-clicked (left) on the header.

So I added to my MESSAGE_MAP:

```
ON_NOTIFY(HDN_ITEMDBLCLICK, 0, OnDblClickHeader)
```

and a function to CMyListCltr:

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnDblClickHeader(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    HD_NOTIFY *phdn = (HD_NOTIFY *)pNMHDR;
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

But: OnDblClickHeader is never called. I tried:

```
ON_NOTIFY
ON_NOTIFY_EX
ON_NOTIFY_RANGE (0-0xffff)
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX
```

... but: OnDblClickHeader is never called.

What might be wrong? Does the header has to get a special style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/hdn-itemdblclick) you have to make sure that your control follows the statement that:
`Only header controls that are set to the HDS_BUTTONS style send this notification code.`

Comment: Thanks. But how do I add the HDS_BUTTONS style when creating the CListCtrl? I'm using PreSubclassWindow to add and remove styles from CListCtrl, bot how/where can I change the style of the header-control?

Comment: You set the initial styles when you create the header control. To retrieve and change the styles after creating the control, use the GetWindowLong and SetWindowLong functions. It's all from the documentation i provided.